# RestSharp query returning NotFound

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

This is my first usage of RestSharp

I am trying to connect to HubSpot using their FormsAPI (https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form)

Using .Net, C#, MVC.

When I run in Fiddler, it works.

Here is my C# code, when I run it, I get a StatusCode of "NotFound". I am sure it is something simple I am missing?

```
 var client = new RestClient("https://api.hsforms.com");
        var request = new RestRequest("submissions/v3/integration/submit/{PortalId}/{formGuid}", Method.POST);


    request.AddUrlSegment("portalId", "[myportalid]");
    request.AddUrlSegment("formGuid", "[myformid]");
    request.AddQueryParameter("hapikey", "[myapikey]");
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddParameter("firstname", "testfirstname");
    request.AddParameter("lastname", "testlastname");
    request.AddParameter("email", "testemail@emailaddress.com");
    request.AddParameter("business_unit", "Test");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create model of c# class and serialize it to Json and send POST request.

1. Example of RestSharp request

```
        public async Task SendHubSpotRequest()
        {
            var PortalId = 1;
            var formGuid = 1;

            var client = new RestClient("https://api.hsforms.com");
            var request = new RestRequest($"submissions/v3/integration/submit/{PortalId}/{formGuid}", Method.POST);

            var hubSpotRequest = new HubSpotRequest()
            {
                SubmittedAt = "1517927174000",
                Fields = new Field[]
                {
                    new Field() { Name = "email", Value = "testemail@emailaddress.com" },
                    new Field() { Name = "firstname", Value = "testfirstname" },
                    new Field() { Name = "lastname", Value = "testlastname" }
                },
                Context = new Context
                {
                    Hutk = "hutk",
                    PageUri = "www.example.com/page",
                    PageName = "Example page"
                },
                LegalConsentOptions = new LegalConsentOptions
                {
                    Consent = new Consent
                    {
                        // Fill other params
                    }
                }
            };
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hubSpotRequest), ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
            var responseContent = response.Content;
        }
```

2. C# classes of body json model

```
public class HubSpotRequest
        {
            [JsonProperty("submittedAt")]
            public string SubmittedAt { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("fields")]
            public Field[] Fields { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("context")]
            public Context Context { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("legalConsentOptions")]
            public LegalConsentOptions LegalConsentOptions { get; set; }
        }

        public class Context
        {
            [JsonProperty("hutk")]
            public string Hutk { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("pageUri")]
            public string PageUri { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("pageName")]
            public string PageName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Field
        {
            [JsonProperty("name")]
            public string Name { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("value")]
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class LegalConsentOptions
        {
            [JsonProperty("consent")]
            public Consent Consent { get; set; }
        }

        public class Consent
        {
            [JsonProperty("consentToProcess")]
            public bool ConsentToProcess { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("communications")]
            public Communication[] Communications { get; set; }
        }

        public class Communication
        {
            [JsonProperty("value")]
            public bool Value { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("subscriptionTypeId")]
            public long SubscriptionTypeId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("text")]
            public string Text { get; set; }
        }
```